# Need help in binding values from child object to parent object

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I've a class inside which there is another class array which contains most of the fields to which I need to pass the data. But When I am passing the data to parent object, I'm getting object reference not set to an instance of object error.

The scenario is something like described below:

```
class Request{
public PriceInfo[] Price{ get; set;}
}

class PriceInfo{
public int PriceID{get; set;} public string Country{get; set;} 
public string Package{get; set;}
}
```

Now in my code, I've instantiated an object of PriceInfo and assigned the appropriate values for each fields.

```
PriceInfo objPrice = new PriceInfo();
objPrice.PriceID = value1;
objPrice.Country = value2;
```

But when I try to assign the value to the parent class object, it throws the error. Say

```
Request objReq = new Request();
objReq.PriceInfo = objPrice  //This line throws the error.
```

How do I pass the data in the objPrice object to the Parent object?

Comment: You should update your code examples to be valid C#.  There is no uppercase C in `class`, and the `extnData` property has no type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this

```
objReq.Price[i] = objPrice
```

cause PriceInfo[] in parent is array of PriceInfo objects not PriceInfo Object

also before adding objects into array see if its initialized, best way is to initialize it in constructor. But I suggest you that you use List because when declaring array you need to add its size which you probably don't know, cause List of PriceInfo is dynamic.

Comment: That solves when you have only one objPrice instance. For my case, I am looping through a gridview and getting the objPrice details and subsequently add it into the objReq object as follow - objReq.PriceInfo[i] = objPrice --this is done inside a for loop....

Comment: the array is called Price, PriceInfo is the class.  Also, it has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array first and then add the object to the array.

```
    objReq.Price = new PriceInfo[1];
    objReq.Price[0] = new PriceInfo();
```

Of course you might initialise the array within your constructor and adjust size accordingly.

`List<PriceInfo>` might be more useful than an array as it is more developer friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default constructor to the Request class that initializes the `PriceInfo` property.  You can then add objects to the array as necessary.

On a side note, use a `List<PriceInfo>` instead of an array.  That would allow you to dynamically add or remove children without reallocating the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a List instead of an Array.

```
public List Price{ get; set;}
```

instead of:

```
public PriceInfo[] Price{ get; set;}
```

and this:

```
Request objReq = new Request();
objReq.PriceInfo.Add(objPrice);
```

instead of:

```
Request objReq = new Request();
objReq.PriceInfo = objPrice;
```